# VS Code - Failing to take input from terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, settings

I am fairly new to tweaking with the settings in VS Code. I have installed the code runner extension on VS Code. I have also updated the settings to make the code run in terminal, instead of the output tab.

This works fine with other languages, but in case of C++, it fails to take inputs and finishes execution as soon as it compiles. What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you should show your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings in VS Code, and look for the property **"Run in Terminal" under Code Runner settings. Check that box, and update your compiler directory.** Once you do this, reload the VS Code window and run your code again, the terminal should take inputs now.